# How to set a create table statement into a variable in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

When I use to execute and write the direct table creation query, it works fine. But when I set the same SQL to a variable and then execute the variable, it does.

```
EXECUTE ( 'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects 
                          WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''DQ_ACC_' + @BUSINESS_NAME + '_OP_BASIC_PROFILE_ENTITY_TREND'') AND type = ''U'')
               CREATE TABLE DQ_ACC_' + @BUSINESS_NAME + '_OP_BASIC_PROFILE_ENTITY_TREND
               (
                   [BUSINESS_NAME] [VARCHAR](200) NULL,
                   [PROFILE_NUM] [INT] NULL,
                   [TABLE_NAME] [VARCHAR](200) NULL,
                   [ATTRIBUTE_COUNT] [INT] NULL,
                   [MIN_ROW_LENGTH] [INT] NULL,
                   [MAX_ROW_LENGTH] [INT] NULL,
                   [NUM_DUPLICATE_RECS] [INT] NULL,
                   [SUMMARY_DETAIL_VIEW] [VARCHAR](100) NULL,
                   [S_KEY] [INT] NULL,
                   [LOAD_TIMESTAMP] [DATETIME] NULL) ON [PRIMARY]'
            );
```

When I assign the same query using the set command, it does not work.

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: first you could check the `@BUSINESS_NAME` whether it has value or `null` ? cause if `null` it will not generate the script.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
DECLARE @Qry VARCHAR(MAX) = 'IF OBJECT_ID(N''DQ_ACC_' + @BUSINESS_NAME + '_OP_BASIC_PROFILE_ENTITY_TREND'' ) IS NULL
                            CREATE TABLE DQ_ACC_' + @BUSINESS_NAME + '_OP_BASIC_PROFILE_ENTITY_TREND
                                    (
                                        [BUSINESS_NAME] [VARCHAR](200) NULL,
                                        [PROFILE_NUM] [INT] NULL,
                                        [TABLE_NAME] [VARCHAR](200) NULL,
                                        [ATTRIBUTE_COUNT] [INT] NULL,
                                        [MIN_ROW_LENGTH] [INT] NULL,
                                        [MAX_ROW_LENGTH] [INT] NULL,
                                        [NUM_DUPLICATE_RECS] [INT] NULL,
                                        [SUMMARY_DETAIL_VIEW] [VARCHAR](100) NULL,
                                        [S_KEY] [INT] NULL,
                                        [LOAD_TIMESTAMP] [DATETIME] NULL
                                    ) ON [PRIMARY]'


            );

EXEC(@Qry)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here i have set value `@BUSINESS_NAME` to 1, then it will generate the create table `SQL` Script :

```
DECLARE @Q NVARCHAR(MAX), @BUSINESS_NAME NVARCHAR(MAX) = '1'

SELECT @Q = N'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''DQ_ACC_' + @BUSINESS_NAME + '_OP_BASIC_PROFILE_ENTITY_TREND'' 
                                                                 ) AND type = ''U'')
                            CREATE TABLE DQ_ACC_' + @BUSINESS_NAME + '_OP_BASIC_PROFILE_ENTITY_TREND
                                    (
                                        [BUSINESS_NAME] [VARCHAR](200) NULL,
                                        [PROFILE_NUM] [INT] NULL,
                                        [TABLE_NAME] [VARCHAR](200) NULL,
                                        [ATTRIBUTE_COUNT] [INT] NULL,
                                        [MIN_ROW_LENGTH] [INT] NULL,
                                        [MAX_ROW_LENGTH] [INT] NULL,
                                        [NUM_DUPLICATE_RECS] [INT] NULL,
                                        [SUMMARY_DETAIL_VIEW] [VARCHAR](100) NULL,
                                        [S_KEY] [INT] NULL,
                                        [LOAD_TIMESTAMP] [DATETIME] NULL
                                    ) ON [PRIMARY]'



 PRINT @Q
--EXECUTE sp_executesql @Q
```

however, if you do not specify the value `@BUSINESS_NAME` then it will not generate the script

Result :

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'DQ_ACC_1_OP_BASIC_PROFILE_ENTITY_TREND' 
                                                                 ) AND type = 'U')
                            CREATE TABLE DQ_ACC_1_OP_BASIC_PROFILE_ENTITY_TREND
                                    (
                                        [BUSINESS_NAME] [VARCHAR](200) NULL,
                                        [PROFILE_NUM] [INT] NULL,
                                        [TABLE_NAME] [VARCHAR](200) NULL,
                                        [ATTRIBUTE_COUNT] [INT] NULL,
                                        [MIN_ROW_LENGTH] [INT] NULL,
                                        [MAX_ROW_LENGTH] [INT] NULL,
                                        [NUM_DUPLICATE_RECS] [INT] NULL,
                                        [SUMMARY_DETAIL_VIEW] [VARCHAR](100) NULL,
                                        [S_KEY] [INT] NULL,
                                        [LOAD_TIMESTAMP] [DATETIME] NULL
                                    ) ON [PRIMARY]
```